# if statement with integers

Tags: java

I'm new at Java. I'm looking for some help with homework. I wont post the full code I was doing that originally but I dont think it will help me learn it.

I have a program working with classes. I have a class that will validate a selection and a class that has my setters and getters and a class that the professor coded with the IO for the program (it's an addres book)

I have a statement in my main like this that says

```
//create new scanner
Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println();
int menuNumber = Validator.getInt(ip, "Enter menu number: ", 1, 3);

if (menuNumber = 1)
{
    //print address book    
}

else if (menuNumber = 2)
{
    // get input from user
}
else 
{
    Exit
}
```

If you look at my if statement `if (menuNumber = 1)` I get a red line that tells me I cannot convert an int to boolean. I thought the answer was `if (menuNumber.equals(1))` but that also gave me a similar error.

I'm not 100% on what I can do to fix it so I wanted to ask for help. Do I need to convert my entry to a string? Right  now my validator looks something like:

```
if (int < 1)
print "Error entry must be 1, 2 or 3)
else if (int > 3) 
print "error entry must 1, 2, or 3)
else 
print "invalid entry"
```

If I convert my main to a string instead of an int wont I have to change this all up as well?

Thanks again for helping me I haven't been diong that great and I want to get a good chunk of the assignment knocked out.

Comment: `=` *assigns* values to variables. `==` tests for equality. And that's not specific to Java ...

Comment: I don't understand why someone voted that question down. It's well written and the problem is obvious by looking at it. I voted +1 to bring it back to 0.

Comment: Also +1 from me for the same reason as @John

Comment: @John - "The problem is obvious by looking at it". Exactly. Note the number one reason for a downvote is *research effort*. This is simply not a question that needs to be asked here, nor would it be beneficial to anyone in the future who at least had opened a beginners programming book and read chapter 1.

Comment: @Brian I can't agree. It's a typical beginners error and I've even seen such bugs in the linux kernel once.
In C you'd not even get any sort of warning, it would just make a change and if unlike zero the if clause would be true.
He clearly invested quite some time in asking the question and writing it proper formated and easy to understand. That should not be punished. Downvoting should be reserved for "extreme cases" imho

Comment: @John I appreciate your comments. I am new at it and I'm struggling through java. I am a television engineer and I get stupid questions all the time. I'm sorry if he thought it was a waste of time but I was stuck and needed a hand through it which is what I thought this site was for. I appreciate your help and anyone elses no matter how lame my questions are.

Comment: @JeremyBorton - StackOverflow is full of absolutely brilliant minds.  Unfortunately, that means that sometimes they see questions like this which are trivial to them, but extremely frustrating for a beginner...especially this common mistake, as it can (in C-ish languages mostly) hide itself by resolving the assignment to something acceptable.  Plus, you formed the question well, tagged as homework, showed work and didn't ask for people to do it for you; don't feel bad, you'll get an upvote from me. There are much more stupid questions floating around.  Don't let anyone deter you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if (menuNumber = 1)
```

should be

```
if (menuNumber == 1)
```

The former assigns the value 1 to `menuNumber`, the latter tests if `menuNumber` is equal to 1.

The reason you get `cannot convert an int to boolean` is that Java expects a boolean in the `if(...)` construct - but `menuNumber` is an `int`.  The expression `menuNumber == 1` returns a boolean, which is what is needed.

It's a common mix-up in various languages. I think you can set the Java compiler to warn you of other likely cases of this error.

---

A trick used in some languages is to do the comparison the other way round:  `(1 == menuNumber)` so that if you accidentally type `=` you will get a compiler error rather than a silent bug.

This is known as a [Yoda Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

---

In Java, a similar trick can be used if you are comparing objects using the `.equals()` method (not `==`), and one of them could be null:

```
if(myString.equals("abc"))
```

may produce a `NullPointerException` if `myString` is null. But:

```
if("abc".equals(myString))
```

will cope, and will just return `false` if `myString` is null.

Answer (score 3):

> I get a red line that tells me I cannot convert an int to boolean.

Thats because `=` is an assignment operator. What you need to use is `==` operator.

Comment: See this is why Java is confusing to me. I should have caught that. So by typing menuNumber = 1 I would be stating that anytime I use the menuNumber I am telling the program it equals 1. 

Thanks

Comment: Was I correct for using menuNumber since I declared it earlier as int menuNumber = validator.getInt ?

Comment: You are not telling `menuNumber` equals to 1. You are saying that I am **assigning** 1 ot `menuNumber`. There is a difference between **assignment** and **equality** in programming languages.

Comment: @JeremyBorton: just think of how much more confused you'd be in a language that will helpfully set the variable to 1 and then treat it as True for you without warning...

Comment: @JeremyB also you should use switch case for such selection scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

A single equal sign is assignment: you assign value to a variable this way. use two equal signs (==) for comparison:

```
if ($menuNumber = 1) {
```

Update: forgot dollar sign: `$menuNumber`